# Xcode C reading in user Text file

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to get the user to input the name of a text file and then open that text file and read the first line of it which tells how many more lines will be read in and allocate space for it. Then I want to store the rest of the lines in the space allocated. I am using a MacBook and using the program Xcode. I am doing the program in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <math.h>       
#include <stdlib.h> 


int main()
{
int MMSize, CacheSize, CBLineSize, SetAsso, NumOfLines, *Num;
char    RepPol, FileNam[75];
FILE    *ptr_file;

printf("Enter the name of the input file containing the list of memory references generated by the CPU: "); 

scanf( "%s", FileNam );
fpurge( stdin );

ptr_file = fopen(FileNam, "r");

 while (ptr_file==NULL){
    printf("failed to open file.\nPlease enter a valid file name: ");

    scanf( "%s", FileNam );
    fpurge( stdin );

    ptr_file = fopen( FileNam , "r" );
}   

fscanf(ptr_file, "%d", &NumOfLines);

Num = malloc(sizeof(int) * NumOfLines); 

for (int i=0; i<NumOfLines; i++) {
    fscanf(ptr_file, "%*[^0123456789]%d", &Num[i]);
            printf("%d\n", Num[i]);
}

    free(Num);
fclose(ptr_file);

return 0;
}
```

My Code runs fine but it always says the input file is NULL. I have saved the input file as file1.txt in the source folder of my project. I have tried typing in the name file1.txt as well as the entire location of the file and the loop runs continuously because it says my file is NULL. However when I go to the file in the finder it has text in it. Can anyone help me with this please.

this works guys. thanks for all the help.

Comment: Are you sure the binary that is execute is at the same folder as your `file1.txt` file?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I do not understand what you mean. my file1.txt is saved in the source file of my project with my main.c. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @Bickson Sure, it's in the same folder as your `main.c` file. However, it's not the `main.c` file that is executed, right? The file is compiled first into a **binary**. So, WHERE is your binary located? Is it in the same folder? (once you give an answer to this question, I think we'll be able to help)

Comment: @Wooble I took a look at that post and I understand how to change the directory path however even when i use the full path and add the /file1.txt to the end my code still returns a NULL and the loop never ends. Is the path I need to change my executable to "file1.txt"?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon My executable file is in a different folder and I have tried to move my text file into the executable folder, however, I was unable to do so. if my executable file is not my binary then I do not know where my binary is compiled.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. First, you ask for a filename, then start a `do` loop that tells the user it couldn't be opened even if it was. Then you try to open a file named "FileNam", not the filename input at the second prompt.

Comment: @Bickson Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @Wooble I enter the do statement and then i have the while statement is that not the correct way to set up "do while" logic? isn't it supposed to "do" whatever "while" whatever condition is met?

Comment: A `do` loop will execute at least once, regardless of whether the condition is true. You just want a `while` loop (and, obviously, to get rid of the quotes in `"FileNam"`).

Comment: @Wooble Okay I see what you are saying. I got rid of the do and the quotes however my program is still returning NULL, when I type in the name of my text file.

Comment: Can you edit the question with your updated code?

Comment: @Wooble My code is now Updated.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys i just figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably closer to what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <math.h>       
#include <stdlib.h> 


int main(void)
{
  int  NumOfLines, *Num;
  char FileNam[75];
  FILE *ptr_file = NULL;

  printf("Enter the name of the input file containing the list of memory references generated by the CPU: "); 

  scanf( "%s", FileNam );
  fpurge( stdin );

  ptr_file = fopen(FileNam, "r");

  while(ptr_file == NULL) {
    printf("failed to open file.\nPlease enter a valid file name: ");

    scanf( "%s", FileNam );
    fpurge( stdin );

    ptr_file = fopen( FileNam, "r" );
  }   

  fscanf(ptr_file, "%d", &NumOfLines);

  Num = malloc(sizeof(int) * NumOfLines); 

  for (int i=0; i<NumOfLines; i++) {
    fscanf(ptr_file, "%d", &Num[i]);
    printf("%d\n", Num[i]);
  }

  free(Num);
  fclose(ptr_file);
  return 0;
}
```

This will take an input file of the format:

```
2
123
456
```

I am guessing from your code what that format should've been. What happens right now is that the first number represents how many more lines there are (so excluding itself). The program then attempts to read that many lines.

Some of the mistakes you made:

- Calling `fopen` with a string literal instead of the variable with the same name
- Using a `do/while` when you meant to use a `while`
- Not dealing with pointers correctly when you allocated your `Num` array

Comment: Thanks Mike I see what you mean. However, I am still having the issue of my file returning Null. No matter How I type it in i am in an infinite loop because it says my file is empty but it is not. I have read some articles saying it may be saved in the wrong location in the Xcode program. do you know anyting about that?

Comment: What is returning `null`? `fopen`? `fopen` returning `null` probably means that the file can't be found. Your input file needs to be in the same directory as the generated program. If not, then you need to specify the full path.

Comment: You were correct now it is reading in the file and outputing it. the input file is

Comment: I have updated my question to show you the input file and the output. do you have any idea why my output is incorrect?